# Имена пакетов в Java в единственном или множественном числе?

Tags: java, package, best-practice

Ситуация следующая:

Всё время делал названия для пакетов в единственном числе, но недавно у друга в коде заметил все названия в множественном. Например: у меня - `dto, controller, model...`, у него - `dtos, controllers, models...`

Стало интересно. Вроде как раньше не задумывался, писал на автомате. Пересмотрел свои исходники, единственный множественный вариант именования - `utils`, всё остальное в единственном числе.

Есть ли какие-то code conventions или best practices в отношении числительного в названии пакета?

Если общих правил не существует, чем следует руководствоваться?

P.S. поиск выдаёт, что многие выбирают совершенно случайно и допускают оба варианта, но какая-то же логика должна быть. Поэтому хочу поднять этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Называйте во множественном числе пакеты с однородным контентом, и в единственном числе — пакеты с разнородным контентом.

Класс имеет сходство с таблицой в базе данных. Таблицу в базе называют в единственном числе, так как записи в таблице являются экземплярами сущности, которая описывается этой таблицей.

Что касается пакетов, то пакет — это не абстракция над данными. Пакет нужен для организации кода и разрешения конфликтов имен. Если пакет назван в единственном числе, то это не значит что каждый элемент внутри пакета является экземпляром данного пакета: он содержит связанные, но разнородные сущности. Если пакет назван во множественном числе, то ожидается, что он будет содержать однородные сущности.

Например, типы следует называть TaskCollection, а не TasksCollection, так как это коллекция, которая содержит Task. Но если пакет назван `com.myproject.task`, то это не означает что каждый класс в этом пакете является экзепляром Task. Там может лежать TaskHandler, TaskFactory и т. д. Но пакет с именем `com.myproject.tasks` будет содержать различные типы тасков: TakeOutGarbageTask, DoTheDishesTask, и т. д.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/75929

Comment: Никогда не видел пакеты с названием repositories, domains, web.rests, dtos, configurations.

Но видел mappers :)

Answer (score 1):

Пишу на c#, в нем не пакеты, а пространства имен и проекты, но суть одна и та же) С основным ответом, полностью согласен, если что-то однородное, зову во множественном числе (Models, Controllers), а если нет, обычно в единственном.
Единственное, что у меня выпадает из этого правила - DTO, т.к. это уже акроним и не вижу смысла добавлять к нему еще S для множественного числа.

Comment: Я сейчас в нескольких чатах этот вопрос поднял, многие пишут, что множественный вариант вообще не нужно использовать, только в единственном. Я уже запутался, не знаю, нужно ли рефакторить старый код или так оставить (в единственном числе)

Comment: Старый рефакторить не надо. Тут как раз важнее сохранять стиль. В новом постарайся выбрать осмысленный подход, который ты потом сможешь и на review обосновать и джунов обучить.

Answer (score 0):

К перечисленным выше ответам хочу добавить.

Поиск по style guides не даёт результатов, так как этот момент не регламентируется.
Вот к примеру от google и oracle рекомендации по названиям пакетов:

[Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.1-package-names)

[Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Поэтому я стал спрашивать в крупных чатах разработчиков java. Большинство особо не задумываются и пишут названия пакетов в единственном числе. Хотя с ответами выше они тоже согласились. В общем, на практике получается единой позиции нет и нужно придерживаться стандартов принятых в вашей компании или в конкретном проекте.